# Unable to click,drag and select form field data on modal in chrome (using nice scroll to the modal causing issue)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, form-fields, nicescroll

Unable to click,drag and select form field data on modal in chrome (using nice scroll to the modal causing issue)?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [«What topics can I ask about here?»](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [«What types of questions should I avoid asking?»](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will make it easier for us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Making Touch Behaviour FALSE worked for me.

info.find('.info-wrapper').niceScroll({ railoffset: { left: -4 }, zindex: 1, autohidemode: false, cursorborder: 0, cursorfixedheight: 76, cursorwidth: 3, cursoropacitymin: 0, cursorcolor: '#ccc', cursoropacitymax: 0.8, **touchbehavior: false**, horizrailenabled: false });